# The best tool to detect anomalies in the log

Tags: logs, log-analysis

I am looking for a log analysis tool, preferably open source, currently using Splunk for free, I would like to detect anomalies.
Can anybody Help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. When you say Financial Transcation log - are you looking to do something like anti- money laundering (AML)? Please clarify. Also state the functions that "Splunk" does that you would like to do.

Comment: @ZZ  No, I edited the question, I'm the similar with splunk, this is not my solution